# mobile safari compatibility

Tags: html, css

I have divs set to be 100% width of the page which works fine in safari big browser, however when I preview the site in mobile safari the divs are sliding left and right and even falling of the page when slid to the left. The fixed nav bar also displays major juddering on scroll in mobile safari?

```css
 /*navlist*/
 .navigation {
   width: 100%;
   background: #fff;
   padding-top: 40px;
   padding-bottom: 40px;
 }
 .navlist {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .navlist:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 1.5px;
   width: 0;
   background: transparent;
   transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
 }
 .navlist:hover:after {
   width: 100%;
   background: grey;
   transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
 }
 /*----/----navlist*/
 /*global styles*/
 body {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   list-style: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 1.05em;
   font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
 }
 a {
   appearance: none;
   font-size: 1.05em;
   font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
   background: transparent;
   color: grey;
   border: none;
   letter-spacing: 0.15em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   transition: color 0.5s ease;
   list-style: none;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 /*----/----global styles*/
 /*navigation icon*/
 #toggle-menu {
   float: right;
   display: block;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   padding: 20px;
 }
 #toggle-menu div {
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   position: relative;
 }
 .header #toggle-menu span {
   display: block;
   width: 15px;
   height: 3px;
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   -webkit-transform-origin: center;
   -moz-transform-origin: center;
   transform-origin: center;
 }
 #toggle-menu span.top {
   top: 0px;
 }
 #toggle-menu span.middle {
   top: 6px;
 }
 #toggle-menu span.bottom {
   top: 12px;
 }
 /*----/----navigation icon*/
 /*Nav Bar*/
 .header {
   /*border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);*/
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 99999;
   background-color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
   /*background: none;*/
 }
 .whitenavbar {
   background: white;
 }
 .nav {
   display: none;
   list-style-type: none;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   left: 0;
   top: 55px;
   border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
   border-top: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #545454;
   font-size: .8em;
   letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 }
 .nav li {
   padding-left: 30px;
   padding-right: 30px;
   background: #fff;
   margin-top: 50px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 .seemore {
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 20px;
 }
 #navpromo {
   border-top: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   background: #ffffff;
 }
 /*----/----Nav Bar*/
 /*in*/
 .in {
   float: left;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   padding: 15px;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: .8em;
   letter-spacing: 0.05em;
   border-top: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
 }
 /*----/----in*/
 /*logo*/
 .logo {
   position: absolute;
   left: 47%;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   padding: 18px;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: .8em;
   letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 }
 /*----/----logo*/
 /*Panels*/
 .projects-container {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   overflow: auto;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display: inline-block;
   -webkit-animation: fadein 3s;
   /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1  */
   -moz-animation: fadein 3s;
   /* Firefox < 16 */
   -ms-animation: fadein 3s;
   /* Internet Explorer */
   -o-animation: fadein 3s;
   /* Opera < 12.1 */
   animation: fadein 3s;
   border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
 }
 .projects {
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   background-size: cover;
   -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
   transition: all 500ms ease-out;
   color: transparent;
   line-height: 200px;
   font-size: 2.5em;
   text-align: center;
   appearance: none;
   font-size: 1.05em;
   font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
   letter-spacing: 0.15em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   list-style: none;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 .projects:hover {
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   background: #DEDDDD;
   opacity: .4;
   color: #545454;
 }
 .panel {
   width: 100%;
   color: #adadad;
   height: 15em;
   padding: 7em;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   background: #ffffff;
   border-top: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
   text-align: center;
 }
 #panel1 {
   background: #b8b8b8;
   height: 30em;
 }
 /*----/----Panels*/
 /****landscape****/
 @media only screen and (max-width: 555px) {
   .nav li {
     display: block;
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
   .navlist:after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     height: 1.5px;
     width: 0;
     background: transparent;
     transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
   }
   .navlist:hover:after {
     width: 100%;
     background: grey;
     transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
   }
 }
 /*----/----Landscape*/
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="" class="in" style="display: inline-block;">
      <svg class="navinstagram" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 155.2 144" style="enable-background:new 0 0 155.2 144;" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M42.7,122.7H21.3V54h21.4V122.7z M32,44.6c-6.8,0-12.4-5.6-12.4-12.4c0-6.8,5.5-12.4,12.4-12.4
    c6.8,0,12.4,5.5,12.4,12.4C44.4,39,38.9,44.6,32,44.6z M122.7,122.7h-21.3V89.3c0-8-0.1-18.2-11.1-18.2c-11.1,0-12.8,8.7-12.8,17.6
    v34H56.1V54h20.5v9.4h0.3c2.8-5.4,9.8-11.1,20.2-11.1c21.6,0,25.6,14.2,25.6,32.7V122.7z" />
        <g>
          <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M151.9,120c0.7-0.1,1-0.5,1-1.1c0-0.8-0.5-1.1-1.4-1.1H150v4h0.6V120h0.7l0,0l1.1,1.7h0.6L151.9,120
        L151.9,120z M151.3,119.6h-0.7v-1.4h0.9c0.4,0,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.6C152.4,119.5,151.9,119.6,151.3,119.6z" />
          <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M151.3,116c-2.1,0-3.8,1.7-3.8,3.8c0,2.1,1.7,3.8,3.8,3.8c2.1,0,3.8-1.7,3.8-3.8
        C155.2,117.6,153.5,116,151.3,116z M151.3,123.1c-1.8,0-3.3-1.4-3.3-3.3c0-1.9,1.4-3.3,3.3-3.3c1.8,0,3.3,1.4,3.3,3.3
        C154.6,121.7,153.2,123.1,151.3,123.1z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </a>

    <a href="" class="logo logocolorchng" style="display: inline-block;">Logo </a>

    <a id="toggle-menu">
      <div>
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="nav">

    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li class="navlist"><a href="" style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navlist"><a href="#panel2" style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navlist"><a href="#wrapper" style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="navpromo">
      <ul>
        <li class="seemore">Want to see more? Check out my instagram!</li>

        <div class='instbtn-cont'>
          <a class='instbtn' href='#'>
       Instagram
        <span class='line-1'></span>
        <span class='line-2'></span>
        <span class='line-3'></span>
        <span class='line-4'></span>
      </a>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="maincontent">
  <div class="panel" id="panel1">
    <div id="hero"></div>
    <div id="scroll">
      <a href="#panel2">
        <span class="arrow-bounce"><svg fill="#FFFFFF" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns= "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="M7.41 7.84L12 12.42l4.59-4.58L18 9.25l-6 6-6-6z"/>
 <path d="M0-.75h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
 </svg>
    </span>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projects-container" id="panel2">
    <div class="projects" style="">
      <span class="project 1">Work Title 1</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="projects-container">
    <div class="projects" style="">
      <span class="project 1">Work Title 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="projects-container">
    <div class="projects" style="">
      <span class="project 1">Work Title 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="projects-container">
    <div class="projects" style="">
      <span class="project 1">Work Title 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="projects-container">
    <div class="projects" style="">
      <span class="project 1">Work Title 5</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="projects-container">
    <div class="projects" style="">
      <span class="project 1">Work Title 6</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a hosted version of the example so we can easily open it in Mobile Safari to test. Also, this does not look like a **minimal** example exhibiting the issue.

Comment: Have you set the viewport? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html